# How do I set the tab title?

Tags: 8, nodes, routes

How do I set the title of the tab from a controller in Drupal 8? This is the code I am using:

#### Controller

```
class myController extends ControllerBase {

    public function node($nId) {
        $nodeObj = Node::load($nId);
        $elements = getRequiredDetails($nodeObj);

        return [
            '#theme'    => 'my_mod',
            '#title'    => 'This is the Tab Title'
            '#contents' => $elements,
            '#attached' => [
                'library'=> [
                    'my_mod/my_mod',
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    /**
    * Returns a page title.
    */
    public function getTitle() {
        $route = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getCurrentRouteMatch()->getRouteObject();

        return $route->getDefaults('#title');
    }
}
```

#### Route

```
my_mod.node:
 path: '/node/{nId}'
 defaults:
   _controller: 'Drupal\my_mod\Controller\myController::node'
   _title_callback: 'Drupal\my_mod\Controller\myController::getTitle'
requirements:
   _permission: 'access content'
```

But the `'#title'` in my controller sets the title in the page, not in the tab.  Is there anything I am doing wrong?

If I put something like `die('Title Here');` in `getTitle()`, it will show in the tab. I need to call that method from the route.

Comment: Which tab? I don't see any tab in the code you have provided.

Comment: I need a title to be set on the browser tab. Looks like `#title` doesnt work for browsers tab head. It only shows title in the contents. @NoSssweat

Comment: Drupal doesn't control what a browser shows in its tabs. By default, it's the page title, but if there are extensions changing the tab title, Drupal cannot do anything.

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of code trying to set titles, Metatag for example does this too, it's pre-configured to set the page title for nodes by this tokens: `[node:title] | [site:name]`.

Comment: @kiamlaluno yes but the thing is my title does not show on the tab. It is just the Drupal Site Name. I guess the default format is **PageTitle | SiteName**. But my one is showing as **| SiteName**

Comment: @4k4 sorry. I didn't get what you have said :(

Comment: Do you have the module Metatag installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [Meta tag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module, you can use following method. From this method you can get Meta tag title and other Meta tags for view section also.

my_module.services.yml

```
services:
my_module.route_subscriber:
class: Drupal\my_module\Routing\RouteSubscriber
tags:
  - { name: event_subscriber }
```

my_module/src/Routing/RouteSubscriber.php

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Routing;

use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

/**
 * Listens to the dynamic route events.
 */
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {

        if ($route = $collection->get('entity.node.canonical')) {
            $route->setDefaults(array(
                '_controller' => 'Drupal\my_module\Controller\MymoduleController::view',
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

MymoduleController.php

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\node\Controller\NodeViewController;

class MymoduleController extends NodeViewController {

    public function view(EntityInterface $node, $view_mode = 'full', 
    $langcode = NULL) {

        $elements = getRequiredDetails($node);

        return [
            '#theme'    => 'your-theme',
            '#contents' => $elements,
            '#attached' => [
                'library'=> [
                    'my_content/my_content',
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```